# Rails original release source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been looking to read some ruby code(specifically Rails) but I don't want to start with the current version of Rails since it has a lot of stuff I don't need and even more stuff that I wouldn't probably understand.

I want to read only the core of Rails and supposedly the early versions were small and kind of easy to wrap one's head around(even for a neophyte like me).

I have tried searching for the original release of rails, but have not been able to find it. The github repo consists of thousands of commits and I don't want to wade through those.

What I want is to know whether there is any place I can get a zip or tar file with the original rails source or even the other early versions. Pointers to links will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

p.s I'm new to ruby programming but not programming in general(I know a little python and scheme) and I understand blocks, lambdas and OO stuff, so I think I can tackle the rails source code. If anyone knows of other ruby projects that make for good code reading, i'd love to know of those too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v0.9.1) the oldest version of rails available on github (v0.9.1). You can download a zip or tar.gz by clicking on the Downloads button.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted and I also learned about accessing github repo versions.

Comment: @user547057 Yeah, in General, you can take a look at the `release` tab in Github, it should contain most of the link to the commit of corresponding releases :) Plus, you might also want to try Gource: http://gource.io/

Answer (score 0):

I would really advice against reading legacy code (which it is). Ruby has changed much since Rails was released and many core features in Ruby (including lambdas, blocks and OO) changed much since.

Instead, try fixing yourself a random gem on github or buy the PickAxe (was only $10 on pragprog last time I checked), in both you can find excellent documentation and examples.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I won't be doing anything useful with the old version, just reading it to get a general idea of rails. I'll be using ony the latest versions for my sites.